# Cant boot anyother option instead HD

Tags: debian, boot, debian-installer, bios

My grandmother gave me a computer, but with Windows, i would like to put Debian on it.

But its not possible to select the boot option...

It starts on this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQZ47.jpg

```
ASUS IN SEARCH OF INCREDIBLE
Please press DEL or F2 to enter UEFI BIOS settings
```

So if i press any of this keys (DEL or F2), shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e61vq.jpg

```
Insertar contraseña
```

So it go back to
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQZ47.jpg

```
ASUS IN SEARCH OF INCREDIBLE
Please press DEL or F2 to enter UEFI BIOS settings
```

And if i press any of this keys (DEL or F2)
It stops on this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNqQm.jpg﻿

```
The system found anauthorized changes on the firware, operating system or UEFI drivers.

Press [N] to run the net boot device, or enter directly to BIOS Setup if there are no other boot devices installed.
Go to BIOS Setup > Advanced > Boot and change the current boot device into other secured boot devices.
```

Hardware information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

Comment: Ask your grandmother for the password?

Comment: she told me, its her name, i'm using the right one.

she dont know how, but she sets a password on bios XD

if i'm want the computer dont even turn on, this screens only shows when i try to press F2 or DEL, if i just let start, its starts windows correcly

Comment: @Otrz As expected. BIOS/UEFI passwords are only required to access their settings, not to boot the installed OS. Now, if it doesn't accept the password - also try uppercase and lowercase combinations - you have to contact the manufacturer and pay for the service. You have UEFI, not BIOS, and that means the password isn't resettable as before and there aren't "master passwords" in a certain website or calculators for that purpose.

Comment: This image: https://imgur.com/YyxfCLz
Shows everytime i start the computer
And it is accepting the password, correctly, if i dont use the right one, the computer even turn on...
How to contact the manufacturer and pay for the service? Sad because this computer is old :(
I cant reset it event knowing the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it formating the HD in other computer