# no internet after apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Tags: debian

My new computer have a problem on BIOS, so i had to format his HD in other computer ([Cant boot anyother option instead HD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529949/cant-boot-anyother-option-instead-hd))

But after i use **apt-get update && apt-get upgrade** and reboot the computer the internet stops to work

What should i do?

Some info hope be useful to someone help me :D

SO? Debian 9

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Loopback Local)
    RX packets 52216  bytes 4228680 (4.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 52216  bytes 4228680 (4.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
```

Comment: lspci says that your NIC is a realtek RTL8111/8168/8411.   Have you loaded the `r8169` kernel module?  do you have the `firmware-realtek` package installed? (this is available `non-free` section of the debian archive)

Comment: i couldnt apt-get install firmware-realtek, because now i have no internet

in other PC i downlod this packages:
https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-realtek/download
this install just fine

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/r8168-dkms/download
but is not
this shows:
Module build for kernel 4.9.0-0-amd64 was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

What it means?

Comment: you only need the `r8168-dkms` package if your realtek nic **isn't** supported by the in-kernel `r8169` driver - it says that in the pkg description.   I've never needed to use it and i've had lots of realtek NICs in lots of different machines over the last 10 years or so.    If you do happen to need it, then you'll need to install the kernel-headers packages for your kernel.  dkms can't compile a module without the headers.

Comment: so, try: 1. `apt-get install firmware-realtek`.  2. `apt-get purge r8168-dkms`. 3. `modprobe r8169`.   4. `ifup eth1` (or the correct device name if it isn't eth1). If that works, add `r8169` to `/etc/modules` and run `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Comment: Is it wifi?  Is there a switch to turn wifi "on/off" on the keyboard (if it's a laptop LOL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it changing in wired config to enp1s0